# Preciso pegar a descrição do processo do Task Manager

Tags: c#, .net, processo

Preciso pegar o nome do processo que esta ativo na tela, porém preciso que trazer igual aparece no Task Manager em descrição.

Por exemplo se eu usar `processName` ele vai trazer "Chrome" eu preciso que seja descrição = Google Chrome.

Já tentei assim:

```
 foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
                {


                    if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
                    {


                        if (app.NomeAplicativo.Contains(p.ProcessName))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Process Name:" + p.ProcessName.ToString());
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("Process Name:" + p.ProcessName);
                    }
                }
```

E usando esse cara:

```
  public static Int32 GetWindowProcessID(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            // Esta função é usada para obter o AID do processo ativo ...
            Int32 pid;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
            return pid;
        }
```

Porém em ambos não consigo pegar a descrição do processo.

Comment: Lucas, baixe o fonte de [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), ali você encontra a forma de fazer esta pesquisa. Mas vai ter de usar chamada de interop.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo essa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6569555/221800) tem uma forma que resolve na maioria das situações, mas não garantidamente. Precisa usar funções da API do Windows que normalmente não estão disponíveis no .NET:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint ProcessId);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

string GetActiveProcessFileName() {
    IntPtr hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    uint pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
    Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
    p.MainModule.FileName.Dump();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enviroment/GetProcessName.cs).

Comment: Eu já tentei fazer isso, só que ao usar o MainModule também não da certo. Ai da o seguinte erro (Não é possível enumerar os módulos do processo.)  E as vezes  dependendo do que esta aberto funciona, mas para alguns aplicativos aberto ele da esse outro erro. (Somente uma parte de um pedido ReadProcessMemory ou WriteProcessMemory foi concluída)

Comment: Não parece existir solução melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza a propriedade *MainWindowTitle* da classe **Process**

Comment: Deu certo usando a propriedade MainWindowTitle. Valeu!